# ODE, dependence on parameter (initial time)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let us consider the Cauchy problem $\dot X=f(t,X)$ with initial condition $X(t_0)=x_0$. Assume that the function $f:[0,T]\times R\to R$ is nice  (e.g., globally Lipschitz and smooth), so that the equation is well-posed. My question is how depends $X(t)$ on the parameter $t_0$ (initial time) for fixed $x_0$? What is the equation satisfied by $\frac{d}{d t_0}X(t)$? This should be an application of parametric version of the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem, but I cannot figure out how to do it...

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the problem as $Y'(s,t_0)=f(t_0+s,Y(s,t_0))$. Then differentiation for $t_0$ gives
$$
\frac∂{∂s}\frac{∂Y}{∂t_0}(s,t_0)=\frac{∂f}{∂t}(t_0+s,Y(s,t_0))+\frac{∂f}{∂x}(t_0+s,Y(s,t_0))\frac{∂Y}{∂t_0}(s,t_0)
$$
with obviously, as the initial state is the same, $\frac{∂Y}{∂t_0}(0,t_0)=0$.